# Do "rage clicks" on navigation that is supposed to be used repeatedly indicate a problem?

Tags: heatmaps

Several click tracking tools track "rage clicks" on elements: ([Crazy Egg](https://support.crazyegg.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500000446581-Understanding-Dead-Space-and-Rage-Clicks), [full story](https://www.fullstory.com/blog/rage-clicks/), [Hotjar](https://www.hotjar.com/blog/rage-clicks/))

These metrics track when a visitor clicks repeatedly in the same spot on the screen. In general that's seen as the person being upset or confused or not finding what they want so they click again to try to get what they do want.

In a report I'm looking at, the previous/next buttons on a dynamic "carousel" or "slider" are being identified as rage clicks.

However, I believe people are clicking repeatedly in that spot of the page because they want to see the next item in the slider.

I can imagine that a website with buttons that are supposed to be clicked repeatedly (video games or media controls) might also identify a commonly used button as a "rage click".

Does anyone have experience and advice on how to interpret "rage clicks" for elements like this? Should they be interpretted as a problem or as proper use of the control (or maybe neither)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully, the tool you're using that identifies rage clicks also has session playback. I think your next step is to watch 10-20 playbacks of that particular area and see how quickly the clicks are happening, and if there are any other frustration signals like mouse thrashing.

You can definitely get rage clicks on an expected area (such as if your carousel is broken), but the only way to know is by user observation and/or checking complaints that come in. (You should also gauge how important the carousel is for a user to complete an important task - is that an area that truly drives people to rage behavior when it can't advance? Or just some nice marketing value props?)